# My laptop's speaker is popping after updating ubuntu 11.10

Tags: speakers

It's not the default alert sound. It's literally pops that happens 3 times in a row really fast. It didn't do this earlier today, but when I updated Ubuntu, the speakers started popping. It does it randomly sometimes, and it does it right before it makes a sound, like before a video or music. Is there a fix to this?

Answer (score 2):

Your problem description matches mine, I found the solution in:
[How do I fix laptop speakers popping when no sound is playing?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/162419/how-do-i-fix-laptop-speakers-popping-when-no-sound-is-playing)

Turns out that the reason was how power save affected my laptops sound card

Adding the link here as this thread was one of the first that turned up when I googled the problem :)

/r

Answer (score 0):

You don't have your cell phone close to the laptop do you? GSM transmissions do make a noise in some speakers.

Answer (score 0):

Try making a fresh install or booting a live CD of Ubuntu 11.10, if there are no issues, maybe is some issue that happened while on the upgrade. Check if you have installed some audio drivers, or if not, check if you can do so. Good luck! ;)