# Lubuntu/Ubuntu 13 Audio clicking in power-save mode

Tags: 13.04, sound, intel

I've recently done a fresh install of Lubuntu 13 on my laptop, I immediately noticed a recurring clicking sound when it wasn't charging.

Running:

```
    lspci | grep -i audio
```

gives:

```
Audio device: Intel Corporation 82801FB/FBM/FR/FW/FRW (ICH6 Family) High Definition Audio Controller (rev 04)
```

Some investigation led me to this question/answer: [How do I fix laptop speakers popping when no sound is playing?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/162419/how-do-i-fix-laptop-speakers-popping-when-no-sound-is-playing/175787)

Running the script fixes the problem which seems to prove that it is related to power-save mode.  Unfortunately I need to run the script every time I reboot.

Does anybody know of a way to make this change permanent, or if there is a better way to go about resolving this?

Answer (score 3):

OK, I've just come across a solution that appears to work, even after a reboot.  I found the solution here: http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1788483 but I'll paraphrase in case the link stops working.

> Open terminal and type:
>
> `gksudo gedit /usr/lib/pm-utils/power.d/intel-audio-powersave`
>
> Find this line:
>
> `INTEL_AUDIO_POWERSAVE=${INTEL_AUDIO_POWERSAVE:-true}`
>
> and comment it out by putting a **#** in front of it like this:
>
> `# INTEL_AUDIO_POWERSAVE=${INTEL_AUDIO_POWERSAVE:-true}`
>
> Just below this line add a new line, like this:
>
> `INTEL_AUDIO_POWERSAVE=false`
>
> So now you will have:
>
> ```
> # INTEL_AUDIO_POWERSAVE=${INTEL_AUDIO_POWERSAVE:-true}
> INTEL_AUDIO_POWERSAVE=false
> ```
>
> Save the file (File > Save) and exit.
>
> Reboot your computer.
>
> The clicking/popping sound will be gone.

Essentially this will stop the Intel driver from putting the hardware into sleep mode.  Not ideal, and hopefully a future update will fix it, but hopefully this will be of help.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the file `audio-power-save-off` which consists your script to run every time your system starts. You have to add it on **Startup Applications**.

- Search for **Startup Applications** on your dash and Run it. You can also find it in directory /usr/share/applications. Just browse it.
- Once started, click <kbd>Add</kbd> button.
- Give some name on first field, <kbd>Browse</kbd> for the file where you stored `audio-power-save-off` for the second field and again give some comment for the third field. Then <kbd>Add</kbd>.
- Your script would be executed each time you starts your system.

Give it a try, hope it works for you..

Also I found [this link](http://en.kioskea.net/faq/3348-ubuntu-executing-a-script-at-startup-and-shutdown)  somewhat important.

Comment: Hi @saurav-kumar, thanks for the quick response.  Unfortunately Lubuntu doesn't seem to come packaged with **Startup Applications** so I tried your second suggestion.  Sadly adding the script into `/etc/rc.local` didn't seem to do anything.  I also tried copying the script to `~/.config/autostart/` but that didn't work either.  I can't find **Startup Applications** in Package Manager or the Software Center?