# External speakers are buzzing when no sound is playing

Tags: sound, pulseaudio, realtek, speakers, dell-vostro

I'm completely new in linux and I was just curious of this OS so here I am.

I mount dual-boot Ubuntu 20.04 LST on my Dell Vostro 5790 and there problem began.
I hear constant, static, annoying, buzzing sound from my external speakers. This occur when:

- no sound is playing in background (when the quietest sound occur speakers are not buzzing and that weird sound coming back after about 5 second of silience)
- sound setting window is opened (when i open sound settings then speakers are not buzzing, after i close this window annoying sound coming back after about 5 seconds)
- I reload alsa `sudo alsa force-reload` (after this sound is completely gone no buzzing and no sound at all)
- when i plug charger this noise is much heavier and louder.

What is completely strange is that when i plug headphones i hear no that annoying sound. When external speakers are unpluged built-in speakers are not buzzing. On Windows10 i have no this problem. That's why I am 95% sure that it is not hardware problem.

I know that above description could looks like duplicate for [Ubuntu 20.04 - After last update, speakers are buzzing unless I open the sound settings window](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1241617/ubuntu-20-04-after-last-update-speakers-are-buzzing-unless-i-open-the-sound-s) but believe me, i tried these solutions already.

Okay, there is what i have tried so far:

- I added `options snd-hda-intel power_save=0 power_save_controller=N` into `/etc/modprobe.d/alsa-base.conf`, saved and restart - nothing changed
- I tried to modify `/etc/default/tlp` and `/etc/tlp.conf` but i have not such files (probably tlp is not installed - i didn't seen it on installed software list)
- I tried reinstall Skype as mentioned here [constant buzzing noise from speaker when headphones are plugged in Ubuntu 13.04](https://askubuntu.com/questions/393026/constant-buzzing-noise-from-speaker-when-headphones-are-plugged-in-ubuntu-13-04)
- I tried adjust `alsamixer` but of course, nothing changed
- I tried to reinstal `alsa-base` and `pulseaudio`
- I tried https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/PulseAudio/Troubleshooting#Glitches,_skips_or_crackling
- I tried [How do I fix laptop speakers popping when no sound is playing?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/162419/how-do-i-fix-laptop-speakers-popping-when-no-sound-is-playing?fbclid=IwAR2aemHM-RExBPSRuSVITYsRnDcCJ9hBeYLxcRWJ9RKNiRIuFuJY-9tnuhc)
- I tried to burn new ISO image on new USB-stick and install new system - nothing changed.

And now I'm out of ideas. I feel like I dig whole internet for this problem.
It drive me crazy so much that I am near to delete and forgete about linux.

Feel free to ask about details.

Please, help.

Comment: "when i plug charger this noise is much heavier and louder" and "When external speakers are unpluged built-in speakers are not buzzing" and "when i plug headphones i hear no that annoying sound" really make me think of a hardware problem. It seems your external speakers are not properly grounded (to the computer). Are they active speakers (brand, type)? Could you check the cable between the 3,5mm audio socket and the speakers? Or maybe even replace it temporarily? What happens when you move the connector around?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

FINALLY!

I found solution for this annoying problem [18.04 audio (Realtek ALC3254) fails on new Dell G3 15 3590](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1220493/18-04-audio-realtek-alc3254-fails-on-new-dell-g3-15-3590)

1. Open terminal
2. Type `sudo nano /etc/default/grub`
3. Find `GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT`
4. Append `snd_hda_intel.dmic_detect=0` (result line should look like `GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash snd_hda_intel.dmic_detect=0`)
5. After save type `sudo update-grub`

Buzzing from speakers are not appear anymore. There is "pop" from speakers when system is booting or switching off but i can live with it.

### EDIT

I played with it a little bit after solving this problem and found that line `options snd-hda-intel power_save=0 power_save_controller=N` in `/etc/modprobe.d/alsa-base.conf` is still necessary.